# Lily of peace. Help please

Tags: peace-lily

I got this yesterday at my Dad's memorial service, I was a dummy and left in the car for about 45 minutes. My mind was working right yesterday.  I came out to this :(   How can I save it ? I will be devastated if I can't save it. [image][image]

Comment: Can this peace lily be saved?
https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4493/1894

Comment: Though this looks like cold damage more than too dry.  Is it cold where you are?

Comment: If its summer where you are, extreme heat inside the car and/or direct sun could have caused this see here https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16329/why-are-the-leaves-of-my-peace-lily-wilted-and-black

Comment: It is clear that the leaf damage can't be reversed. Some of the leaves look like they have undamaged tissue left though. You can remove the damaged leaves/tissue with scissors and if the crown of the plant and the roots are not damaged, The plant will grow back in time.

Answer (score 0):

None of that foliage can be saved. The plant itself will be fine if properly cared for from now on. A semi-heavy pruning is in order for that plant along with some consistent TLC from now on.